# How to force m2eclipse to look for new dependencies after network outage?

Tags: java, m2eclipse, maven-3

we are using m2eclipse 0.12.1 together with nexus oss 1.9.0.1 repository. Today, during a downtime of the nexus server, some user did use "update dependencies" in m2eclipse, which did result in a broken project configuration (artifact not found ... for nearly all dependencies)

The problem is, after the nexus server comes back online, update dependences still did not work, it seems not trying to reach the server. The only brute force sollution which did work was to delete the local repository. Then all dependencies got successfully downloaded.

So, it seems the local metadata went corrupt, or tell m2eclipse not to look on the server again. 
How to force m2eclipse to download the dependencies? Or how to tell m2eclipse to enable the nexus server again ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to remove all "*.lastUpdated"-files from your local Maven repository.

On Linux you can use this line to do that:

```
find ~/.m2/repository -name "*lastUpdated" -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm
```

And then use Maven -> Update Dependencies in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks a lot removing *lastUpdated file helps a lot if you manually messed your repository.

Answer (score 1):

Do a "project clean" for all projects or, if this doesn't eliminate the build path errors, restart eclipse with the clean option.

If all doesn't help: create a new workspace and (physically) import all projects through the eclipse IDE. This will create new project metadata and leave the old workspace unaffected.

Comment: Project clean for all projects didn't help. It looked fine at first, but at the end it did complain about missing dependencies again :( The create new Workspace also doesn't sound very promising, all settings are lost, so wiping the local repository is easer (although it takes > 10 minutes to download all dependencies again)